# How to count the number of occurences of a string across a range in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas, google-query-language

I've tried combining vlookup and countif functions - match function. But none of them are the actual solution to the problem given how they are supposed to work. I've gone through their documentation. Below is a snippet of the data I have. I have to count how many time H3, H4 and so on occur in the range from A to G columns - these columns are of unequal length. Please help me understand how I can do this.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

paste in i3 cell

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H3:H, QUERY(FLATTEN(A3:G), 
"select Col1,count(Col1) 
 where Col1 is not null 
 group by Col1 
 label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0)))
```